# Play audio from API response JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to play a downloaded audio file and play it back in the browser from an external API.

I have a local API which is querying an external API where the file is located. My API method to get the file from the external API is:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAudioAsync(string id)
{
    using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
        httpClientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        var url = "externalapi/"

        using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {
            var result = await client.GetAsync(url);

            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            var bytes = await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);

            response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = bytes.LongLength;

            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "audio.wav";
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("audio/wav");

            return response;
        }                    
    }
}
```

I know that in Javascript I can set the source attribute of an audio element to playback audio. How do I take the data response from this API method and play the audio?

I've tried the following code below but I get console errors.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'api/' + id,
  cache: false,
  type: 'GET'
}).done(function (data) {
  // var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'audio/wav'});
  // Creating a blob instance removes the error but the audio is not correctly loaded to the audio element. I get no playback.      
  document.getElementById('filename').setAttribute('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(data));
}).fail(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

The error I get back from the browser is: ERROR TypeError: Failed to construct 'Blob': Iterator getter is not callable.

The response I get back from my local API is:

```
{
    "version": {
        "major": 1,
        "minor": 1,
        "build": -1,
        "revision": -1,
        "majorRevision": -1,
        "minorRevision": -1
    },
    "content": {
        "headers": [
            {
                "key": "Content-Length",
                "value": [
                    "0"
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "Content-Disposition",
                "value": [
                    "attachment; filename=audio.wav"
                ]
            },
            {
                "key": "Content-Type",
                "value": [
                    "application/octet-stream"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "statusCode": 200,
    "reasonPhrase": "OK",
    "headers": [],
    "requestMessage": null,
    "isSuccessStatusCode": true
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I think the issue may be that when I console.log(data) I get back an object rather than an array of bytes. That can be used to initialize a Blob object.

Comment: can you please supply us with the errors you are receiving in the console?

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt ERROR TypeError: Failed to construct 'Blob': Iterator getter is not callable.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the contents of your `voiceRecording.audio.done` method?

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt I've added the contents of the function.

Comment: Have you tried just to set the URL of the audio element to the API enpoint? The audio element should know how to handle the response.

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt Can you provide an example? I'm not sure I quite understand what you mean, sorry.

Comment: Please see updated answer for some more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `audio` elements `src` attribute to point directly to the ASP.NET Web API endpoint:

```
<audio src="http://localhost:8000/api/endpoint/callId"></audio>
```

If you need to set it dynamically you can do it via javascript:

```
function setAudioElementSource(id)
{ 
  document.getElementById('yourAudioElement').setAttribute('src', 'http://localhost:8000/api/endpoint/callId')
}
```

Where `endpoint` is the name of your `Controller` and `callId` is the id of your call.

Here is an example of my action returning the call:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAudioAsync(
    string id)
{
    var url = "http://localhost:8000/api/ExternalApi";

    using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        httpClientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;                

        using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {
            var result = await client.GetAsync(url);

            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            var bytes = await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);

            response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = bytes.LongLength;

            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "audio.wav";
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("audio/wav");

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the response captured in Fiddler:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: audio/wav
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=audio.wav
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcdGphYXJ0LnZhbmRlcndhbHRcZG9jdW1lbnRzXHZpc3VhbCBzdHVkaW8gMjAxNVxQcm9qZWN0c1xXZWJBcHBsaWNhdGlvbjFcV2ViQXBwbGljYXRpb24xXGFwaVxkb3dubG9hZFwxMjM=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 20 Aug 2018 09:12:45 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Content-Length is 0 as I am returning a blank byte array in my `ExternalApi` method, your Content-Length header should have a value greater than 0.

If you are not getting any errors, please try a different browser, some browsers do not support playback of `.wav` files

---

**Side note**:

You can also create a custom class `FileResponse` that inherits from `HttpResponseMessage`

```
public class FileResponse
     : HttpResponseMessage
{
    public FileResponse(
          byte[] fileContent
        , string mediaType
        , string fileName)
    {
        StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
        Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(fileContent));
        Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(mediaType);
        Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = fileName };
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAudioAsync(
    string id)
{
    var url = "http://localhost:8000/api/ExternalApi";

    using (var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler())
    {
        httpClientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = true;                

        using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {
            var result = await client.GetAsync(url);                    

            var bytes = await result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            return new FileResponse(bytes, "audio/wav", "your-file-name.wav");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @CallumOsborn Can you be more specific?  What did it actually do?  Did it throw an error?  What was the response code for the request?  If you give a more detailed response, it will help Tjaart amend his answer appropriately.

Comment: @TjaartvanderWalt I don't get an error in the console from doing: document.getElementById('yourAudioElement').setAttribute('src', 'http://localhost:8000/api/endpoint/callId'). In fact nothing really happens. I go to click the audio element and it "flashes" but does not play any sound.